# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when invoking a method on This?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a method on the current object that takes a parameter.  Invoking the method throws a `NullPointerException`, even though `this` *by definition* must not be `null`.

```
private String doSomething(int i){
   return "I";
}
```

Invocation:

```
Integer i = null;
String s = this.doSomething(i);
```

Why is there a `NullPointerException` if I'm not referencing a `null` object?

Comment: Why the downvotes, is something wrong with the question?

Comment: Please see [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Comment: +1...more people should answer their own questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the JVM internals are throwing a `NullPointerException` because of the inability to convert a `Integer i` to the `int i`.  In this case the `Integer` is `null`, which of course is not valid for the [primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `int`.

This is not a permitted conversion, per the [specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/autoboxing.html), and noted in [the guide for Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Can someone explain why the JVM would be unable to unbox an `Integer`?

Comment: @TylerTreat The `Integer` is `null`, which isn't a valid `int.

Comment: Oh, duh! Didn't notice you assigned it as null. :p

Comment: @TylerTreat I didn't noticed I defined the method as `int`, for at least thirty minutes.  Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

JVM tries to autobox null to int and failed with a NPE.